# Is there a way (preferably in R) to automate extracting information from the BirdLife Data Zone?

Tags: r, database, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to extract information from the [BirdLife Data Zone](http://datazone.birdlife.org/home), such as altitude and countries where a species occurs, for a large group of species of study interest. So far I have been doing this by hand, but it is a very time consuming process. I was wondering if there was R code which would let me do this automatically for the species which I am interested in. This is not about extracting IBAs, which you can get on request, but about extracting data which is in the data tables for each species.

So far I have been searching each species and then manually inputting the data I am interested in into my excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you provide examples of your input (e.g., a few bird species and how they’re formatted) and desired output (e.g., what you’ve been manually entering in Excel)?

Comment: I have it in excel where the first column is species name, second and third columns are traits which I already have data on in this format, and fourth and fifth column are data which I am entering manually from BirdLife Data Zone.

Comment: Please run `dput()` on the .xlsx file you imported into R and copy the result into your question. Also, add information about what data you want to extract and which columns the data are in. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL structure is actually quite straightforward:
`datazone.birdlife.org/species/factsheet/<hyphenated-species-name>/details`
brings you straight to the page with all the tables. Using `rvest::html_table()`, with help from stringr to make the URLs and purrr to `safely()` `map()` over multiple species:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

species <- c("northern rockhopper penguin", "flame-colored tanager", "Siberian crane")

urls <- paste0(
  "http://datazone.birdlife.org/species/factsheet/",
  str_replace_all(str_to_lower(species), " ", "-"),
  "/details"
)

names(urls) <- species

dat <- map(urls, safely(\(x) html_table(read_html(x)))) |>
  list_transpose()
```

Peeking at the first few tables for the northern rockhopper penguin:

```
#> dat$result$`northern rockhopper penguin`[1:3]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  `Critically Endangered` Endangered        Vulnerable                
  <chr>                   <chr>             <chr>                     
1 -                       A2acde+3cde+4acde A2acde+3cde+4acde; B2ab(v)

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 × 3
    Year Category       Criteria                       
   <int> <chr>          <chr>                          
 1  2020 Endangered     "A2acde+3cde+4acde"            
 2  2018 Endangered     "A2acde+3cde+4acde"            
 3  2016 Endangered     "A2acde+3cde+4acde"            
 4  2012 Endangered     "A2acde+3cde+4acde"            
 5  2010 Endangered     "A2a,c,d,e; A3c,d,e; A4a,c,d,e"
 6  2008 Endangered     "A2a,c,d,e; A3c,d,e; A4a,c,d,e"
 7  2004 Not Recognised ""                             
 8  2000 Not Recognised ""                             
 9  1994 Not Recognised ""                             
10  1988 Not Recognised ""                             

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  X1               X2             X3                X4                             
  <chr>            <chr>          <chr>             <chr>                          
1 Migratory status "full migrant" Forest dependency Does not normally occur in for…
2 Land mass type   ""             Average mass      -
```

Of course, you'll have to further manipulate these tables to extract the information you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was looking for. I have on query, and apologies if it is presumptuous, but how would one be able to manipulate this to extract the information that I need. Is there a function that does the job of saying "only include altitude information" or "only include countries where it is found" Or "Only include its IUCN status"?

Comment: If the information you want is always in the 3rd, 6th, and 7th tables on the page, say, you could do something like `html_table(read_html(x))[c(3,6,7)]`, or `map(dat$result, \(x) x[c(3,6,7)])`.